# Issue with ORM Lite Composite Key Workaround

Tags: ormlite-servicestack

I am implementing the composite key workaround suggested here:

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/#limitations

but I'm getting the SQL error "Invalid column name 'ID'" when trying to SELECT using the composite key values.  SQL Profiler shows that the SELECT does indeed include a column 'ID' so I understand the SQL error.  I'm just not sure how to use the workaround without getting the error?

DTO:

```
public class EmploymentHistory {
    [PrimaryKey]                        // Workaround - Composite Key => Unique Key
    public string ID {
        get {
            return
                this.EmployeeID + "|"
                +
                this.DepartmentID + "|"
                +
                this.TitleID + "|"
                +
                this.StartDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        }
    }
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public int TitleID { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }

    [Ignore]
    public Department Department { get; set; }
    [Ignore]
    public Title Title { get; set; }
}
```

Request DTO:

```
[Route("/employmenthistory/{EmployeeID}/{DepartmentID}/{TitleID}/{StartDate}", "GET")]
public class SingleEmploymentHistoryRequest : IReturn<Employee> {
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public int TitleID { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
}
```

Service method:

```
public object Get(SingleEmploymentHistoryRequest request) {
    EmploymentHistory employmentHistory = Db.Select<EmploymentHistory>()
        .Where(eh =>
            eh.EmployeeID == request.EmployeeID
            &&
            eh.DepartmentID == request.DepartmentID
            &&
            eh.TitleID == request.TitleID
            &&
            eh.StartDate.Date == request.StartDate.Date).FirstOrDefault();

    if (employmentHistory == null)
        throw new WebServiceException("EmploymentHistory not found");

    return employmentHistory;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to specify a fake `ID` primary key for custom queries:

```
var employmentHistory = Db.Single<EmploymentHistory>(eh =>
    eh.EmployeeID == request.EmployeeID &&
    eh.DepartmentID == request.DepartmentID &&
    eh.TitleID == request.TitleID &&
    eh.StartDate >= startDate.Date && 
    eh.StartDate < startDate.Date.AddDays(1)));
```

Comment: I thought I needed the ID as described in the "Limitations" section - "You can still SELECT from these tables, you will just be unable to make use of APIs that rely on it, e.g. Update or Delete where the filter is implied (i.e. not specified), all the APIs that end with ById, etc."  Are you saying I can't have it both ways?  With fake ID, I get a SQL error when SELECTing, without it I don't get Update, Delete, etc.?

Comment: Multiple Primary Keys are not supported, the computed property is a hack to make it work for API's relying on an implicit ID, e.g. INSERT/UPDATE's. Custom SELECT's don't rely on single primary key, they're also different in that you can use a different model to select a subset of properties from the table model - I'll see if I can make it work for computed read-only properties without breaking anything and get back to you.

Comment: @jaybird BTW the issue is that the `ID` field still needs to exist in the underlying table. If you don't want to have an `ID` field you can remove it and you'll still be able to `db.Select()` (not SingleById) and `db.Insert()` but you wont be able to call `db.Update(poco)` without specifying the Request Filter since OrmLite wont be able to determine what the PK is, so you'll need to use a `where:` expression on Updates (important). Personally I'd just add an autoincrementing `Id` column to the table and not use Multiple Primary Key's.

Comment: @jaybird Also you can't query sub properties on Date's like that, I've added an example showing an alternative solution.

Comment: Thanks @mythz - I think we'll just add an auto-incrementing Id column - I'm tired of this table anyway...